# How to enable state field in Temporary Address when i click the checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When i enter the `Permanent Address` then i click checkbox the value of `Permanent Address` will be displayed in the `Temporary Address` field But sate field is not bind in the `Temporary Address` field

```
<h5 class="with-border">Permanent Address </h5>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                                <label class="form-label semibold control-label">Address line 1</label>
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.pharmaCompanyDivision.PAddress1, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtPPAddress1", placeholder = "Address Line1" })
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                                <label class="form-label semibold control-label">Address Line2</label>
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.pharmaCompanyDivision.PAddress2, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtPPAddress2", placeholder = "Address Line2" })
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                                <label class="form-label semibold control-label">Country</label>
                                                @Html.DropDownList("CountryNew", null, "--- Select Country ---", new { @class = "select2-arrow" })
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!--.row-->
                                    <br />
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                                <label class="form-label semibold control-label">State</label>
                                                <select id="stateNew" class="select2-arrow"></select>
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                                <label class="form-label semibold control-label">City</label>
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.pharmaCompanyDivision.PCity, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtPPCity", placeholder = "City" })
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                                <label class="form-label semibold control-label">Pincode</label>
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.pharmaCompanyDivision.PPinCode, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtPPPinCode", placeholder = "Pincode" })
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!--.row-->
                                    <br />
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                                <label class="form-label semibold control-label">Land Mark</label>
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.pharmaCompanyDivision.PLandMark, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtPPLandMark", placeholder = "Land Mark" })
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                                <label class="form-label semibold control-label">Phone No</label>
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.pharmaCompanyDivision.PPhoneNo, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtPPPhoneNo", placeholder = "Phone Number" })
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                                <label class="form-label semibold control-label">Mobile Number</label>
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.pharmaCompanyDivision.PMobileNo, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtPPMobileNo", placeholder = "Mobile Number" })
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!--.row-->
                                    <br />
                                    <br />
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="check-1">
                                        <label for="check-1">Billing Address is same as Shipping Address.</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <br />
                                    <br />
                                    <h5 class="with-border">Temporary Address </h5>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                                <label class="form-label semibold control-label">Address line 1</label>
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.pharmaCompanyDivision.TAddress1, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtTAddress1", placeholder = "Address Line1" })
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                                <label class="form-label semibold control-label">Address Line2</label>
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.pharmaCompanyDivision.TAddress2, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtTAddress2", placeholder = "Address Line2" })
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                                <label class="form-label semibold control-label">Country</label>
                                                @Html.DropDownList("CountryNew1", null, "--- Select Country ---", new { @class = "select2-arrow" })
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!--.row-->
                                    <br />
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                                <label class="form-label semibold control-label">State</label>
                                                <select id="stateNew1" class="select2-arrow"></select>
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                                <label class="form-label semibold control-label">City</label>
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.pharmaCompanyDivision.TCity, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtTCity", placeholder = "City" })
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                                <label class="form-label semibold control-label">Pincode</label>
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.pharmaCompanyDivision.TPinCode, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtTPinCode", placeholder = "Pincode" })
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!--.row-->
                                    <br />
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                                <label class="form-label semibold control-label">Land Mark</label>
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.pharmaCompanyDivision.TLandMark, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtTLandMark", placeholder = "Land Mark" })
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                                <label class="form-label semibold control-label">Phone No</label>
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.pharmaCompanyDivision.TPhoneNo, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtTPhoneNo", placeholder = "Phone Number" })
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                                <label class="form-label semibold control-label">Mobile Number</label>
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.pharmaCompanyDivision.TMobileNo, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtTMobileNo", placeholder = "Mobile Number" })
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!--.row-->
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('input:checkbox[id*=check-1]').change(function () {

            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('input:text[id*=txtTAddress1]').val($('input:text[id*=txtPPAddress1]').val());
                $('input:text[id*=txtTAddress2]').val($('input:text[id*=txtPPAddress2]').val()); 
                $('select[id*=CountryNew1]').val($('select[id*=CountryNew]').val()); 
                $('select[id*=stateNew1]').val($('select[id*=stateNew]').val()); 
                $('input:text[id*=txtTCity]').val($('input:text[id*=txtPPCity]').val()); 
                $('input:text[id*=txtTPinCode]').val($('input:text[id*=txtPPPinCode]').val()); 
                $('input:text[id*=txtTLandMark]').val($('input:text[id*=txtPPLandMark]').val());
                $('input:text[id*=txtTPhoneNo]').val($('input:text[id*=txtPPPhoneNo]').val());
                $('input:text[id*=txtTMobileNo]').val($('input:text[id*=txtPPMobileNo]').val());
            }
            else {
                $('input:text[id*=txtTAddress1]').val('');
                $('input:text[id*=txtTAddress2]').val('');
                $('select[id*=CountryNew1]').val('');
                $('select[id*=stateNew1]').val('');
                $('select[id*=txtTCity]').val('');
                $('select[id*=txtTPinCode]').val('');
                $('select[id*=txtTLandMark]').val('');
                $('select[id*=txtTPhoneNo]').val('');
                $('select[id*=txtTMobileNo]').val('');
            }
        });
    });
```

Image[image: Not Pass]

State bind code Example:

```
$("#CountryNew").change(function () {
                    var id = $(this).val();
                    $("#stateNew").empty();
                    $.get("State_BindNew", { CountryID: id }, function (data) {
                        var v = "<option>--- Select State ---</option>";
                        $.each(data, function (i, v1) {
                            v += "<option value=" + v1.Value + ">" + v1.Text + "</option>";
                        });
                        $("#stateNew").html(v);
                    });
            });

            $("#CountryNew1").change(function () {
                var id = $(this).val();
                $("#stateNew1").empty();
                $.get("State_BindNew1", { CountryID: id }, function (data) {
                    var v = "<option>--- Select State ---</option>";
                    $.each(data, function (i, v1) {
                        v += "<option value=" + v1.Value + ">" + v1.Text + "</option>";
                    });
                    $("#stateNew1").html(v);
                });
            });
```

Comment: Deleting a question on which you received a good answer is disrespectful to those who took the time to help you. I've undeleted this question for that reason. Do not make a pattern of this, or you will find yourself unable to ask any questions.

Answer (score 1):

The `stateNew1` dropdown's options are fetched via an ajax when `CountryNew1` value gets changed. The ajax takes some time to complete. So, you're basically setting the `stateNew1`'s value even before the options are loaded.

You can fix this by setting the value of `stateNew1` **after** the options are populated. Change the `CountryNew1`'s change event to:

```
$("#CountryNew1").change(function () {
    var id = $(this).val();
    $("#stateNew1").empty();
    $.get("State_BindNew1", { CountryID: id }, function (data) {
        var v = "<option>--- Select State ---</option>";
        $.each(data, function (i, v1) {
            v += "<option value=" + v1.Value + ">" + v1.Text + "</option>";
        });
        $("#stateNew1").html(v);
        // check of checkbox is checked
        if($('#check-1').is(":checked")) {
           $("#stateNew1").val($('#stateNew').val()); // set the "stateNew" value to "stateNew1"
        }
    });
});
```

And you don't need to use [Attribute Contains Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) if you have the exact `id` values.